# Getting "ConnectException" when trying to access a service

Tags: java, linux, connection, rmi

I am getting the following error when i try to access application on server lonrs07471 (linux)

> Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host:
>   lonrs07471.fm.rbsgrp.net; nested exception is: 
>     java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect  at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.rbs.marketrisk.client.rmi.RmiClientHelper.lookupRemotePrivate(RmiClientHelper.java:175)
>     at
>   com.rbs.marketrisk.client.rmi.RmiClientHelper.lookupRemote(RmiClientHelper.java:74)
>     at
>   com.rbs.marketrisk.common.domain.service.binding.AbstractRmiServiceBindingStrategy.createService(AbstractRmiServiceBindingStrategy.java:43)
>     ... 24 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:
>   connect   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown
>   Source)   ... 32 more

I have no clue what does this mean and how to resolve this though i read about rmiregistery thing. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: lonrs07471.fm.rbsgrp.net; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source) at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source) at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source) at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source) at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source) at
```

As it is thrown by `Registry.lookup()`, it means you're trying to connect to the RMI Registry, and there isn't one running at the host you specified.